# ComboBox selected value is disappearing on clicking somewhere else or by tab indexing to other control in .net Windows form

Tags: winforms

I have created a form which contains a combo box (cmbOccupation) that is bind with a data source(bsOccupation). When I run the application, I get the desired value getting displayed as a drop down list of the combo box. However, when the combo box loose it focus or when I click somewhere else or I tab it to the next control, its selected value get disappeared. I don't know what is happening here so I thought of asking this question. I haven't use any event that is making the value to disappear(like lost event focus or leave event). Below is designer code that I used:

```
        // 
        // cmbOccupation
        // 
        this.cmbOccupation.AllowDrop = true;
        this.cmbOccupation.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.bsabc, "IndustryCode", true));
        this.cmbOccupation.DataSource = this.bsOccupation;
        this.cmbOccupation.DisplayMember = "Description";
        this.cmbOccupation.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.cmbOccupation.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cmbOccupation.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(177, 165);
        this.cmbOccupation.MaxDropDownItems = 10;
        this.cmbOccupation.Name = "cmbOccupation";
        this.cmbOccupation.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(229, 21);
        this.cmbOccupation.TabIndex = 703;
        this.cmbOccupation.Tag = "Disable";
        this.cmbOccupation.ValueMember = "IndustryCode";
        // 
        // bsOccupation
        // 
        this.bsOccupation.DataSource = typeof(CS.Entities.Industry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting your Databinding?

I think that the problem is there and with the DataSource is enough. I am trying to reporduce this error.. But if I have no binding, and only have the DataSource property set to some source (like a listBox) for example.. if I lose focus from my comboBox for example changing the tab and then comming back, the value is still there.

I hope this helps ;)